# How to debug the background behaviour of an application?

Tags: android, debugging, background, alarmmanager, battery

I get this behavior for my app in Settings->Battery:

```
CPU Total : 9m30s
CPU foreground : 23s
Keep awake : 0s
Wi-Fi running : 4s
...
Computed power used : 60mAh
```

I see the battery draining and the phone heating up. So clearly my app is doing something there. But what?

My general question is how to debug (best practice, tools) what my application is really doing?

Regarding this specific case, I will add that the app uses the AlarmManager:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, 0, ONE_HOUR_MS, pendingIntent);
```

I have tried to fire up traceview on a debug version of the app, but the thread waken up by the AlarmManager is quickly finished and no other thread that belongs to the app process is doing any work.

Answer (score 1):

To achive your goal there is a tool called Systrace.

[Systrace](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/systrace.html)